# Neo4j: Filter nodes based on aggregate function

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Suppose I have a list of customer nodes and a list of orders each customer has placed represented as order nodes associated to these customer nodes. Each order has a cost numeric property associated to it.

I want to return those customers, whose average order is greater than a threshold. Here is some non-functioning code that exemplifies what I want:

```
MATCH (n0:Customer)-[]-(n1:Order)
WITH n1.cost as cost
WHERE avg(cost) > 300
RETURN n0, avg(cost)
```

But of course this is not quite right. How should I go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is close, you just need to do the aggregation in the `WITH` statement, not the `WHERE` clause

```
MATCH (n0:Customer)-[]-(n1:Order)
WITH n0, avg(n1.cost) AS cost WHERE cost > 300
RETURN n0, cost
```

Comment: Can you explain the difference?