# Filter nodes based on two aggregate functions applied to two subset of children nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

This is an extension of ([Neo4j: Filter nodes based on aggregate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45601919/neo4j-filter-nodes-based-on-aggregate-function))

Suppose I have a set of customer nodes and a set of orders each customer has placed associated to these nodes. Each order node has two properties associated to it: a cost and a store where the order was placed. I want to extract those customers whose average order at storeA exceeds 300 but at the same time his average order at store B is below 100. Here is my (non functioning) attempt at doing this:

```
MATCH (n0:Customer)-[]->(n1:Order {store: 'storeA'})
WITH n0, avg(n1.cost) as average_storeA WHERE average_storeA > 300
WITH (n0:Customer)-[]->(n2:Order {store: 'storeB'})
WITH n0, avg(n2.cost) as average_storeB where average_storeB < 100
return n0
```

The problem being that in line number 3 the WITH statement returns an error where it doesn't know what `n2` means. How can I pipe the results of a previous match statement to a new match statement where new node queries/variables are introduced? I imagine you could try two independent match queries and then finding the intersection between the node sets, but this should be much slower than applying a second filter on top of an already filtered set of nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `WITH` in the line 3 you should `MATCH` the new pattern using the previous `n0` variable, like this:

```
MATCH (n0:Customer)-[]->(n1:Order {store: 'storeA'})
WITH n0, avg(n1.cost) as average_storeA WHERE average_storeA > 300
MATCH (n0)-[]->(n2:Order {store: 'storeB'})
WITH n0, avg(n2.cost) as average_storeB where average_storeB < 100
return n0
```

Comment: Thank you. For some reason I thought that introducing match would create a new n0 variable separate from the one on the first line. I guess I'm just not clear on when to use MATCH vs WITH when piping results other than aggregate functions.